# "You have one new answer" message

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, recent-activity

Sometime I get a "You have one new answer" message. But when I click on the envelope, there appears no new answers.

It's not that often, but every now and then I get this message.

Comment: Might have been deleted before you got to it.

Answer (score 3):

As [Shog9 says here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44158/you-have-1-new-answer-see-your-responses-link-doesnt-show-any-responses/44167#44167), it was an issue with new edits being grouped with new answers - this has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could have already seen the "new" answers. There's a delay between any new answers and the system flagging the new answer. One could have looked at the new answers and it would still be flagged later.

Answer (score 1):

It might be an answer from yesterday (in SO time) that is not shown on the "recent" page anymore. Click on "yesterday" (or even earlier) to see it.

**Edit:** Now that I find this old answer of mine, I have to say that I have experienced similar quite often.

Comment: That's not it; I posted a more detailed dupe at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44158/you-have-1-new-answer-see-your-responses-link-doesnt-show-any-responses and got linked here.

Comment: @romkyns: I know, I was the one who linked you. You should add your info as an answer to this post, so all reports concerning the same (possible) bug are in one place.