# גun truthfull alerts "You have a new response/answer"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“You have one new answer” message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13040/you-have-one-new-answer-message)

Many times when I open the site (and I open it many times a day) I get the alert "You have new answer" but when I click it, I see nothing.
This is somewhat annoying.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13040/you-have-one-new-answer-message

Comment: Am I the only one that sees un truthfull alerts “You have a new response/גanswer [closed]” on the page title under Chrome?

Comment: @voyager I see "גun truthfull alerts “You have a new response/answer [closed]" on Firefox. Weird.

Comment: @Daniel, It also displays that way for me on Chrome & IE

Comment: I see it... I see it