# Super User answer notification bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications

All day I've been getting notifications that I have *"1 new answer"*.  But my recent activities page doesn't show anything new (other than a couple of comment responses on answers I've posted).

I've checked all my questions ([it's a short list](https://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A12786+views%3A1)) and there aren't any new-and-deleted answers on any of them.  There is [a Community Wiki question](https://superuser.com/questions/111152/whats-the-proper-way-to-prepare-chroot-to-recover-a-broken-linux-installation) whose answer [got edited](https://superuser.com/posts/111215/revisions) a couple of times today.

So maybe I'm not familiar enough with question-asking; do answer edits re-notify the question asker?  Or is this a bug in the notification system?  Or is something else going on?

Comment: "do answer edits re-notify the question asker" No. At least they didn't so far.

Comment: @balpha: thx.  i didn't think so, but it's the only "working-by-design" explanation i can think of.

Comment: I can imagine it's on purpose, though. It would make some sense. Then again, it should also appear on the recent activity page in that case.

Comment: maybe this is related to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41507/notification-when-a-question-or-answer-is-revised-is-not-really-status-completed .. but if so i can't find the edit.

Comment: well maybe if someone SENT US AN EMAIL we could contact you

Comment: this is likely a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13040/you-have-one-new-answer-message ... haven't seen this crop up again and expect if i do it won't have the same cause.

Comment: Dupe http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39059/number-of-answers-indicated-by-notification-is-one-more-than-actual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed - [see Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44158/you-have-1-new-answer-see-your-responses-link-doesnt-show-any-responses/44167#44167) for details!