# Notification on edited answers

Tags: support, edits, accepted-answer, notifications

If I edit my answer on SO, after this answer was accepted by the owner of the question, will the owner receive a notification of any sort?

Comment: I don't think question owners get notification of edits to answers regardless of whether the answer has been accepted or not.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42891/superuser-answer-notification-bug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

You can leave them a comment (either a *@reply* or on the question), or perhaps they're watching their profile page for recent activity on their questions (the *recent* button), or watching that question's RSS feed (generally unlikely, but useful for me).

(Now this has been edited after being accepted, as proof to the OP.)

Answer (score 3):

The [new notification system](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/) includes edits:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm I only get this randomly....

Comment: @ama yeah, don't recall seeing it recently. Maybe there are some constraints (no notification for retagging, minor edits, etc)