# Does the OP of a question get a message in the inbox when I update my answer?

Tags: support, answers, edits, global-inbox

Does the OP of a question get a message in the inbox when I update my answer?

Or do I have to make all the time a comment saying "@OP I updated my answer".

(Its a bit annoying when there are a lot of requests coming after the answer, and SO suggests to move the discussion automatically to chat)

Comment: you should now have notifiers from this comment and my answer...

Comment: @Rory, yes I got two messages in my inbox, one because of your comment to my post and one because you **added** an answer to my question. But my assumption is (I am not sure!) if you now edit your answer, I will not get a message in my inbox.

Comment: ahh @Stema - I see what you mean. I updated my answer so you should hopefully have another 2 notifiers, one from this comment, and one from the updated answer.

Comment: @Rory, no I got only a message about a new comment, but no notification about the edit of the answer. Thanks for your support! I think I will then make a feature request.

Comment: @stema: Did you already do a search? I'm pretty sure this has been asked (and even requested) before.

Comment: @Stema - useful testing. I had thought that you would get a notifier. I have updated my answer to reflect our new understanding :-)

Comment: @Hendrik, yes I did a search on meta and found nothing that answered my question.

Comment: @stema: Try [this query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bnotification+%2Bedit). I didn't find feature-requests, however.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notification on edited answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43451/notification-on-edited-answers)

Comment: @Hendrik, I have seen now a lot of stuff in this direction, but I think my question has not been asked before.

Comment: @Cody This question is not exactly the same, but the answer and comments to it would have answered my question, too.

Comment: That seems like as good a measure of a duplicate as anything else...

Comment: @Cody I agree, I haven't seen this question before, if so I wouldn't have asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No - Testing demonstrates that while you get a notifier when someone adds an answer or comment on one of your posts you do not get one when an answer or comment is updated.

Comment: if you update your answer to reflect our test result, I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: Has there ever been easier rep on SE? :)