# Notify when someone edits an answer to your question

Tags: feature-request, answers, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notify users about edit suggestion on their own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91556/notify-users-about-edit-suggestion-on-their-own-posts)

When an answer is edited and editor hasn't notified me about edit (using comment), there's no way of knowing about this edit. When question is new, I came to know about it most of times because I check answers often. But, when question is old, I miss edits most of times.

So, it'd be nice if you add this feature.

Comment: This might shed some light on the decision **not** to have this feature : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97756/172936