# Notify the asker that an answer has been edited when an update has been asked

Tags: feature-request, answers, edits, notifications

I often see the following scenario :

- a user answers a question
- the asker posts a comment because something is unclear
- the answerer edits the post
- the answerer posts a comment (*"See my edit."*) to notify the OP.

If the asker can be notified automatically when the answer has been edited, the answerer will not have to post a "useless" comment, just to notify the asker.

So what I propose is to add a checkbox when the original answerer edits an answer to notify the asker of the modification.

Of course no one want to be notified for every edits, the checkbox should only be enabled in these cases:

- the checkbox is a privilege earned after, at least 5K or 10K rep.
- the checkbox can only be used if the asker post a comment on the answer.

It's maybe to much work for a tiny feature, but I want to share this idea.

*PS : I read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64692/179059), asked 2 years ago but my request is different.*

Comment: This doesn't sound like a bad idea, although the way I would implement it is a checkbox next to each answer, saying "Notify me when this answer is updated" so the question asker (or maybe anyone else?) could be notified (by email? by inbox?).

Comment: @JimmyPena Thanks for the comment. The problem in this way is the risk to receive too much notifications. Indeed if the answerer edits his post many times because of spelling errors (for example). The "follower" will be notified many times for updates that don't impact the answer meaning.

Comment: What's the difference to [Notify question OP (and those who marked it a favourite) if an answer has been modified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64692/notify-question-op-and-those-who-marked-it-a-favourite-if-an-answer-has-been-m)?

Comment: Also: [Optional notification on an edit to an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97740/146482)