# Could we have a way to notify users when an answer is edited?

Tags: feature-request, answers, notifications, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Optional notification on an edit to an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97740/optional-notification-on-an-edit-to-an-answer)

Many times I answer the question to the best of my ability, then the question asker replies with a comment or edits their question because I didn't quite give the help they needed. So I edit my answer to fix whatever the issue was... and then I leave a comment like "check out my edit".

I don't like having to leave that comment. It bloats the comments for no reason. But I've found that when I ask a question, I often go do other things on the site while I wait for responses.

Could we let a question asker know that an answer to one of their questions has been edited?