# "You have 1 new answer. See your responses." link doesn't show any responses

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, notifications, recent-activity

This has been confusing me for ages. I go to StackOverflow. I see the link at the top saying that I have a new answer. I click it. It shows "nothing".

I click "this week", "last week" - they all show "nothing".

I click "this month", and the *most recent answer* is one that I have seen three times before.

So I have no idea what this link is telling me about. Where is this new answer? Why does this keep happening so often? It's either a bug or bad UI.

Comment: Yep, that's a known bug (at least it has been reported quite a few times). See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13040/you-have-one-new-answer-message for example

Comment: I am positive it's neither of the two suggested answers in that link, and since I am unable to edit the other bugreport to add more details I propose to keep this one :)

Comment: i posted a similar mystery; see if anything looks familiar. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42891/superuser-answer-notification-bug

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the "revisions" tab on that screen: [one of your questions was edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815492/how-to-determine-whether-a-net-exception-is-being-handled) 21 hours ago, and that would trigger the notification while not showing anything on the summary page...

Yes, it would be more helpful if the notification said "*n* new revision(s) to your post(s)".

Comment: Indeed, thanks! Hoping to see this fixed...

Comment: That's totally the issue - we'll look at it!

Comment: We split out the edits - the query included them incorrectly in the answer total.  You'll now see counts for new answers, comments, and edits.