# "You have 1 new answer. See your responses." banner doesn't disappear when the answer is removed

Tags: bug, notification-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“You have 1 new answer. See your responses.” link doesn't show any responses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44158/you-have-1-new-answer-see-your-responses-link-doesnt-show-any-responses)

I update SU, see "You have 1 new answer. See your responses.". I click "responses" and see nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4701/have-recent-activity-default-to-show-something and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/clicking-envelope-beside-username-shows-fewer-recent-activities-than-today-butt. Though neither really contain my answer (*I think*).

Comment: I mean the banner should not appear if answer it refers is deleted.

Comment: I see, let me remove my answer then. ;)

Comment: You removed the answer, and now I have a badge "Student" but with no answers to my questions. Bug of feature?

Comment: The student badge just means you have a question with upvotes.

Comment: Resolved via [this change](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/)?

Comment: @Jim, I don't know, need to experiment to see. Answer to some of my questions (e.g. to this) and then immediately delete the answer. Expected: no red circle notice for me.