# message: 1 new answer, but only 1 revision

Tags: bug, notification-bar

Hi,
On SO I've got the following orange message:

> "You have 1 new answer and 1 new
>   comment. See your responses."

But I have only 1 comment and 1 new revision of my question, no new answer. Did I overlook something?

Comment: I _believe_ this is obsolete now that the "see your responses" functionality has changed. Voting to close. Feel free to smack me (in a comment) if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the other post on Meta, but a moderator mentioned that as a bug recently - revisions to your posts count as new answers.

Edit: aha, found the link
["You have 1 new answer. See your responses." link doesn't show any responses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44158/you-have-1-new-answer-see-your-responses-link-doesnt-show-any-responses/44167#44167)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably deleted.

Or you didn't click `Today` first (by default only the last 3 hours of responses are displayed when clicking on the envelope).