# Cannot get rid of "You have 1 new answer" bar

Tags: support, stack-overflow, notification-bar

"You have 1 new answer. See your responses." However, all my responses page shows is "maximum of 90 days allowed". Same for summary, reputation, favorites, revisions and badges. I also went on my profile and visited all of my previous questions, yet the bar still shows up.

I see that there have been reports of similar problems in the past, mostly answered with a link to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44158/you-have-1-new-answer-see-your-responses-link-doesnt-show-any-responses/44167#44167) by Shog9. However, in my case the revisions tabs is also empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the boxed "x" to the right of the notification to dismiss it.

---

In response to your comment:

To view replies this aged, you will have to manually edit the address in the address bar:

> http://[stack-exchange-site]/users/recent/[your-user-id]?StartDate=[start-date]&EndDate=[end-date]

Note that the two dates must be in the form `YYYY-MM-DD`, and they refer to the time period which you want to search between.

In addition, looking at your [Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151238/lac), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786687/svn-undo-delete-before-commit/3717665#3717665) was the one you most recently received, so it may have been alerting you to that.

Comment: OK, that was the stupidest answer I've ever asked anywhere. I blame overeating and undersleeping. However, what I really meant to ask was how I could track down this new answer. It's too old to show up in the responses page, but clearly the "new answers bar" still remembers it. I didn't want to clear the bar until I found the answer, but at some point I must have become convinced that finding the answer was the only way to clear the bar. So, ok, the bar is gone, but is there anything that could be done about these phantom notifications? Maybe extending the time limit on the responses page?

Comment: @LaC Updated my answer to answer your real question. By the way, I think you meant "the stupidest *question* I've ever asked" in your comment. :)

Comment: I am the stupidest.